# Integrating IdentityServer4 to ASP.NET Core MVC and API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC application that register/login users using ASP.NET Identity by providing a registration/login form or using Google OAuth. Now we want to build a mobile application to use our API server (build with ASP.NET Core Web API hosted in a sub-domain of the website) but we want to have the same register/login flow in that too.

I dig around and find out that IdentityServer4 has the necessary features to support our needs and read its documentation but unfortunately I couldn't make it to work as I wanted to.

The scenario is that we have a Web Application, Web API and a Mobile application which all of them should use same register login flow which is to register and login in the application or use Google OAuth.

I appreciate if anyone can point me to a good documentation or sample code for both MVC client application and Identity Server (for authentication) with the same requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication) samples, it will give you a good place to start. That sample has MVC client using implicit flow for authentication against the identity provider. You can easily extend the controllers (like [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) one for example) with routes and code to do registration logic. [This](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal) sample does external login using google for your convenience. For mobile you would probably want to use Hybrid grant/flow and depending on your platform/device google can help you find libraries to do this.

HTH

Comment: see here for a .net based library for native/mobile clients: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2